# Moving conditional element rendering into a separate function within the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to move a part of the code where it gets very repetitive into a function within the same component.

Here is what it would look like before moving this conditional statement into a separate function...

```
                <div className="col-4">
                    {parts.map(part => (
                        part.active[0] && <div key={part.bodyPart}>{part.bodyPart}</div>
                    ))}
                </div>
```

and I'm trying to move it so it would look something like this in the function.

```
    const showParts = (activeIndex) => {
        return parts.map(part => (            
            //this one does not work
            part.active[activeIndex] && <div key={part.bodyPart}>{part.bodyPart}</div>

            //but for some reason, this works below without the conditional statement
            /* <div key={part.bodyPart}>{part.bodyPart}</div> */

        ))
    }
```

And here's what it would look like in the return statement.

```
    return (
        <div className="container text-center">
            <div className="row rows-cols-3">
                <div className="col-4">
                    {showParts(0)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

I know that the conditional statement is causing the issue but I'm not sure what bracket or return statement I'm missing in the function to make it work.

It's also confusing because I am not getting any error with the conditional statement I have it on here.

Also, here's what the 'parts' state looks like.

```
const [parts, setParts] = useState([
        { bodyPart: "upperLip", price: 1000, active: [true, true, true] }]
```

Thanks!

Comment: This code seems to run fine, I think you might be missing some details: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-m5cqlj?file=App.tsx what is the parts array and what is the error? Please edit your question to include those details: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74707958/edit

Comment: My parts array is an array of objects. It looks something like this.
const [parts, setParts] = useState([
        { bodyPart: "upperLip", price: 1000, active: [false, false, false] },
        { bodyPart: "chin", price: 1000, active: [false, false, false] }])

Comment: So you expect nothing to show up since `part.active[1]` is false? Did you mean to write `activeIndex` instead of `1`?

Comment: Sorry, I should've fixed that little part. I current have part.active[1] set to true manually so it shouldn't affect the outcome. But I'll go ahead and make the change here.

Comment: So there's no error, it's just nothing was showing up. So I'm guessing the index you were using was false?

Comment: Well... that's the weird part, I've set all three of them in an array as 'true' so I know the condition will be will be met.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in the stackblitz I linked? Also, you have a random curly brace at the end of your declaration of `parts`, hopefully that's just a typo.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked after I just reworked my code to make it look like yours in stacklitz. Here's the code for other people who are wondering.
    const showParts = (activeIndex) => {
        return parts.map(
            (part) => part.active[activeIndex] && (<div key={part.bodyPart}>{part.bodyPart}</div>)
        )
    }